# Intel Wireless 8260 - This Device is not working - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

I am new to ubuntu, previous heavy user of windows and microsoft products, wanting to take back control of my digital privacy.

After a fresh install of 20.04LTS I noticed in the *Software & Updates* application under *Additional Drivers* tab that my Intel Wireless 8260 status is *this device is not working* with *Do not use the device* checkbox ticked.

However my wifi works fine and have connected to multiple networks and can surf the internet.

when I run the following command *lshw -C network*
terminal returns:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 3a
       serial: e4:a4:71:11:15:70
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-29-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.1.177 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:141 memory:ddc00000-ddc01fff
```

I can see that it is using the correct driver and that it is working. is this a bug with the *Software & Update* application or is there something I can do to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: "Is this a bug with the Software & Update application" Yes, it is. Please ignore it and enjoy your working wireless. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Same issue in my case. But there might something wierd going one with the wifi too:
` ModemManager[1144]: <warn>  Modem couldn't be initialized: Couldn't check unlock status: SIM not inserted
 ModemManager[1144]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> failed)
 NetworkManager[988]: <info>  [1590002201.7069] device (cdc-wdm0): modem state 'failed'
 NetworkManager[988]: <info>  [1590002201.7172] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to retrieve SIM object: No SIM object available
 bluetoothd[1089]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)`